# Opening a window in a specific workspace?

Tags: window-manager, window-management, wmctrl

In Ubuntu 14.04, is it possible (perhaps using wmctrl?) to activate an instance of a window in a specific workspace?

Example: Suppose I'm in workspace 1, and I have a google-chrome window open in workspace 4.  Is there a way to use a command to go straight to that google-chrome window in workspace 4 (ignoring any in workspace 1)?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be faster using `Ctrl + Alt + Up` than you will see all workspaces and windows opened on them.